# How do I enable s3 bucket Default Encryption programmatically with AWSSDK?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to enable default encryption for s3 Bucket programmatically. Following is not working no errors as well. Anybody know the reason for this ?

```
        private async Task<PutBucketEncryptionResponse> EnableServerSideEncriptionAsync(string bucketName)
    {
        return await S3Client.PutBucketEncryptionAsync(new PutBucketEncryptionRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration = new ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration()
            {
                ServerSideEncryptionRules = new List<ServerSideEncryptionRule>()
                {
                    new ServerSideEncryptionRule()
                    {
                        ServerSideEncryptionByDefault = new ServerSideEncryptionByDefault()
                        {
                            ServerSideEncryptionAlgorithm = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTencryption.html) says it "sets default encryption for a buckets". How are you checking the result?

Comment: I am Checking it from the aws console. Bucket properties. I am expecting default Encryption is enabled after executing my code. am I Wrong ?

Answer (score 17):

I tried it using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to see what would happen.

I created a new bucket, and ran:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket my-bucket --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
```

I then went to the bucket in the Amazon S3 console, clicked the **Properties tab** and the **Default Encryption** box displayed: ***AES-256***

[image: S3 Bucket default encryption]

Comment: Thank you very much  John Rotenstein. Unfortunately I need to do this stuff through the lambda function and c# code. Do you see any issue with my code ?

Comment: If it matches my `s3api` call, then it should do the same thing. Perhaps you can try things to force an error, such as putting an incorrect Bucket name, just to confirm that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: My C# code matching to your command and if I pass invalid bucket name i am getting error "The specified bucket not exist". When I pass the valid bucket name I am getting response as follows.

{"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"ECEB6BECEB6BECEB6B","Metadata":{"x-amz-id-2":"SfllUyBhiRGG4PwOoVGrJgOlUyBhiRGG4PwOoVGrJgOlUyBhiRGG4PwOoVGrJgOlUyBhiRGG4PwOoVGrJgO/A="}},"ContentLength":0,"HttpStatusCode":200}"}

Will there be time delay ? I checked after few hours. still not will check again in tomorrow as well.

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right, then (although perhaps try it as sync rather than async?). Just try to get the message shown in the picture above.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no sync method in AWSSDK. But when I am calling using await.

Comment: Thanks, with your code, I have successfully enabled the all my s3 buckets' encryption with Ansible `local_action: command aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket {{ item }} --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules":[{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault":{"SSEAlgorithm":"AES256"}}]}'   --profile dev`  **Need remove the space behind the ':'**, or yaml will through error `"reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Answer (score 2):

Finally this is end up with an permission issue. I didn't have permission to see the status of default encryption. users who has permission could see default encryption is enabled.

Thank you John Rotenstein for your time to find solution for this issue.

> Hope that aws console shows an message saying "Access Denied" instead
>   of showing wrong default encryption is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Good night, I had the same problem an hour ago and maybe I found the solution! 
Code:

```
private async void EncryptBucket(string bucketName)
{
    var encryptResquest = new PutBucketEncryptionRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration = new ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration()
        {
            ServerSideEncryptionRules = new List<ServerSideEncryptionRule>()
            {
                new ServerSideEncryptionRule()
                {
                    ServerSideEncryptionByDefault = new ServerSideEncryptionByDefault()
                    {
                       ServerSideEncryptionAlgorithm = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AWSKMS,
                       ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId = "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:**insert your account id**:alias/aws/s3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for bucket_name in $(aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name" --output text);
do
        if (aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket ${bucket_name})
        then
                echo "already encrypted"
        else
                echo "doing encrption"
                aws s3api put-bucket-encryption  --bucket ${bucket_name} --server-side-encryption-configuration  '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
                echo "done encrption"
        fi
done
```